# Type errors with generic class that uses an enum on construction

Tags: typescript

I've boiled down a case I have to the following. Type inference isn't working as I'm expecting below, I have three errors that I've inlined as comments.

```js
enum Type { A = 'A', B = 'B' }

interface ThingA { type: Type.A; }
interface ThingB { type: Type.B; }

type Thing<T extends Type> =
  T extends Type.A ? ThingA :
  T extends Type.B ? ThingB :
  never;

class Wrapper<T extends Type> {
  type: T;

  constructor(thing: Thing<T>) {
    // Type 'Type' is not assignable to type 'T'
    this.type = thing.type;
  }
}

function run<T extends Type>(wrapper: Wrapper<T>): T {
  switch (wrapper.type) {
    // Argument of type 'Wrapper<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Wrapper<Type.A>'.
    // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Type.A'.
    // Type 'Type' is not assignable to type 'Type.A'.
    case Type.A: return getTypeA(wrapper);

    // Same error as above but with Type.B
    case Type.B: return getTypeB(wrapper);
  }
}

function getTypeA(wrapper: Wrapper<Type.A>) { return wrapper.type; }
function getTypeB(wrapper: Wrapper<Type.B>) { return wrapper.type; }
```

It's unclear to me why this won't work, as it seems relatively straightforward. Perhaps my approach is fundamentally flawed?

Comment: For your first problem I'd make `type Thing<T extends Type> = Extract<ThingA | ThingB, {type: T}>`.  For your second problem you will probably need type assertions or overloads, since the underlying problem is that you [can't narrow generics the way you can narrow values of concrete union types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995), at least not yet.